# Simple AVG in pig groups?

Tags: apache-pig

I have a very simple 2-column data, with a double and a chararray:

```
user1 234.43
user1 432.23
user2 4321.213
etc.
```

I want to group by users, then compute the average of their doubles. How? Do I need a "GROUP * ALL"? I'm trying to follow Example 2 http://wiki.apache.org/pig/PigOverview , but it's not working for me.

```
selfReportsAndDiscrepancies = FOREACH discrepancies1 GENERATE discrepancy,selfReportedText;
perDiscrepancy = GROUP selfReportsAndDiscrepancies BY selfReportedText;

allDiscrep = group perDiscrepancy all;

means = FOREACH allDiscrep GENERATE AVG(perDiscrepancy.discrepancy);

DUMP means;
DESCRIBE means;
```

gives me:

```
2013-04-02 17:54:06,611 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1128: Cannot find field discrepancy in group:chararray,selfReportsAndDiscrepancies:bag{:tuple(discrepancy:double,selfReportedText:chararray)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood you correctly, you want the average of the group averages:

```
VISITS = LOAD 'data' USING PigStorage(' ')  AS (user:chararray, number:double);
USER_VISITS = GROUP VISITS BY user;
USER_AVG = FOREACH USER_VISITS GENERATE group AS user, AVG(VISITS.number) AS average;
ALL_AVG = GROUP USER_AVG ALL;
OVERALL_AVG = FOREACH ALL_AVG GENERATE AVG(USER_AVG.average);
DUMP OVERALL_AVG;
```

Results in:

```
(2327.2715)
```

Comment: Thanks. I had a bug (I had a UDF that was appending Strings, it should have been doubles). This does work.